# How can I read the Uploaded CSV file without saving it to Server?

Tags: c#, csv

Hi all, I have CSV files which are in this format:

```
**CSV Format1**

  ||OrderGUID||OrderItemID||Qty||SKUID||TrackingNumber||TotalWeight||DateShipped||DateDelivered||ShippingStatusId||OrderShippingAddressId
  ||5        ||3          ||2  ||12312||aasdasd       ||24         ||2012-12-2010||            || 10025          ||10028
  ||5        ||4          ||3  ||113123||adadasdasd   ||22         ||2012-12-2012||            ||10026           ||10028



**CSV Format2**

    ||"OrderGUID"||"OrderItemID"||"Qty"||"SKUID"||"TrackingNumber"||"TotalWeight"||"DateShipped"||"DateDelivered"||"ShippingStatusId"||"OrderShippingAddressId"||
    ||"5"        ||"3"          ||"2"  ||"12312"||"aasdasd"       ||"24"         ||"2012-12-2010"||""            || "10025"          ||"10028"||
    ||"5"        ||"4"          ||"3"  ||"113123"||"adadasdasd"   ||"22"         ||"2012-12-2012"|| "2012-12-2010" ||"10026"           ||"10028"||
```

I have to read these files without saving them on the server. Can anyone help me? How can I read this files and insert in my db? How can I trim the special characters from the files?

This is what I am trying to do for the file upload:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult ImportTrackingNumber(FormCollection form,HttpPostedFileBase UploadedFile,TrackingNumbersModel Trackingnumbers)
{
    if (UploadedFile != null)
    {
        var allowedExtensions = new[] {".xlsx", ".csv"};
        if (UploadedFile.ContentLength > 0)
        {                   
            var extension = Path.GetExtension(UploadedFile.FileName);
            if (extension == ".xlsx")
            {
                //Need To code For Excel Files Reading
            }
            else if (extension == ".csv")
            {
                //string filename = Path.GetFileName(UploadedFile.PostedFile.InputStream);
                StreamReader csvreader = new StreamReader(UploadedFile.FileName);
                DataTable dt;        
            }
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: `StreamReader csvreader = new StreamReader(UploadedFile.InputStream);`?

Comment: Further to Mario's comment: the `FileName` property returns the name or path of the uploaded file **on the client**. Your code is running on the server, and cannot directly read files from the client.

Comment: @RichardDeeming How do i use delimeter for removing special chars

Answer (score 47):

Just an example on how you can read the uploaded file without saving it on the server:

```
// Use the InputStream to get the actual stream sent.
using (StreamReader csvReader = new StreamReader(UploadedFile.InputStream)) 
{
    while (!csvReader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = csvReader.ReadLine();
        var values = line.Split(';');
    }
}
```

Comment: would it not be better to have line.Split('/n') since a csv file will use commas to seperate values and a new line '/n' to seperate lines?

Comment: Well, no =) In this case `line` is already a "line" (`csvreader.ReadLine()` will give you the whole line/row and has logic to identify the end of a line), and thus `line.Split('/n')` will have no effect, nor is it a char or valid C#.

Comment: If its for  <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload" runat="server" Width="300" /> then StreamReader csvreader = new StreamReader(fileUpload.Postedfile.InputStream);

Comment: should it not be split by line.Split(','); ?

Comment: @markthewizard1234 Sure, if comma is used as the delimiter, but it doesn't really matter if it's comma, semicolon or some other char that's used as the delimiter as long as it's not used in the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code:

```
public static DataTable GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    DataTable csvDataTable = new DataTable();

    // Read bytes from http input stream
    var csvBody = string.Empty;

    using (BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream))
    {
        byte[] binData = b.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);
        csvBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(binData);
    }

    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);
    streamWriter.Write(csvBody);
    streamWriter.Flush();
    memoryStream.Position = 0;

    using (TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(memoryStream))
    {
        csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
        csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
        string[] colFields = csvReader.ReadFields();
        foreach (string column in colFields)
        {
            DataColumn datecolumn = new DataColumn(column);
            datecolumn.AllowDBNull = true;
            csvDataTable.Columns.Add(datecolumn);
        }
        while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
        {
            string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();
            //Making empty value as null
            for (int i = 0; i < fieldData.Length; i++)
            {
                if (fieldData[i] == "")
                {
                    fieldData[i] = null;
                }
            }

            csvDataTable.Rows.Add(fieldData);
        }
    }

    return csvDataTable;
}
```